# format output in Prolog

Tags: prolog

i have this [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) code in Prolog.

```
astar(Start,Final,Path,Tp):-
      estimation(Start,Final,E),
      astar1([(E,E,0,[Start])],Final,Path,Tp).

astar1([(_,_,Tp,[Final|R])|_],Final,L3,Tp):-
      reverse([Final|R],L3).    %write('Path = '),write(L3).
astar1([(_,_,P,[X|R1])|R2],Final,C,Tp):-
       findall((NewSum,E1,NP,[Z,X|R1]),(adjacent(X,Z,V),
               \+(member(Z,R1)),
               NP is P+V,
               estimation(Z,Final,E1),
               NewSum is E1+NP),L),
               append(R2,L,R3),
               sort(R3,R4),
               astar1(R4,Final,C,Tp).

estimation(_,_,0).
```

this is the base of knowledge.

```
line(orange, subway, [
         [jarry,2],
         [jean_talon,1],
         [beaubien,2],
         [champ_de_mars,1]
         ], [[5,24],3,[0,33]], [[5,30],3,[0,30]]
).
line(blue, subway, [
         [fabre,2],
         [jean_talon,1]
         ], [[5,30],3,[0,45]], [[5,30],3,[0,45]]
).
```

this is an example of the output of the A* code:

```
?- astar(fabre,beaubien,Path,Time).
Path = [fabre, jean_talon, beaubien],
Time = 3 ;
```

But I want the output to look like this. In this example, *jean_talon* is an intersection between 2 lines of subway. That's why this station is represented in the blue and orange line.

```
Path = (blue, subway, [fabre, jean_talon]),  (orange, subway, [jean_talon, beaubien])].
```

how to format the output in Prolog?

Comment: Note that the `adjacent/3` predicate is missing, so the code doesn't run as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is already a snippet to format the station list into a list of station pairs:

```
myformat([Station|Stations],Result) :- 
   myformat3(Station,Stations,Result).

myformat3(PrevStation,[C|Stations],[[PrevStation,C]|Result]) :-
   Stations \= [],!,
   myformat3(C,Stations,Result).

myformat3(PrevStation,[C],[[PrevStation,C]]).
```

So:

```
?- myformat([fabre, jean_talon, beaubien],Result).
Result = [[fabre, jean_talon], [jean_talon, beaubien]].
```

Now to extend this...

Note that you are using what looks like tuples `(A,B,C,D)` for the result, but these are used to express conjunctions. They are nasty to compose properly, because they are actually tree structures like so:

```
       ,
      / \
     A   ,
        / \ 
       B   ,
          / \
         C   D
```

I will just use a proper list instead: `[A,B,C,D]`, which is in-style with Prolog.

```
       .
      / \
     A   .
        / \ 
       B   .
          / \
         C   .
            / \
           D   []
```

In SWI-Prolog, the `.` above is replaced by `[|]`.

```
decorate([[A,B]|Pairs],[Decoration|Result]):-
   line(Color,Type,Details,_,_),                   % grab a line...
   append([_,[[A,_TimeA],[B,_TimeB]],_],Details),  % ...in which the sublist for A,B appears
   Decoration = (Color,Type,[A,B]),                % compose what is actually a paranthesized CONJUNCTION
   decorate(Pairs,Result).
decorate([],[]).
```

And now:

```
rt(Result) :- myformat([fabre, jean_talon, beaubien],Pairlist),
              decorate(Pairlist,Result).


?- rt(X).
X = [(blue, subway, [fabre, jean_talon]),  (orange, subway, [jean_talon, beaubien])] ;
```